# User Roles not updating for entity framework in customroleprovider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a app with the following relationship between user and role:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .HasMany(c => c.Roles)
                .WithMany(p => p.Users)
                .Map(
                   m => {
                       m.MapLeftKey("UserId");
                       m.MapRightKey("RoleId");
                       m.ToTable("UserRole");
                   });
```

Pretty standard stuff. Ihave a customRoleProvider set up as follows:

```
    public class CustomRoleProvider : RoleProvider
        {
            private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

            public CustomRoleProvider()
            {
                _unitOfWork = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUnitOfWork>();
            }

            public CustomRoleProvider(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
            {
                _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            }

...

            public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
            {
                var user = _unitOfWork.UserRepository.GetUser(username);

                var roles = from r in user.Roles
                            select r.Name;

                if (roles != null)
                    return roles.ToArray();
                else
                    return new string[] { };
            }

            public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)
            {
                var user = _unitOfWork.UserRepository.GetUser(username);

                var roles = from r in user.Roles
                            select r.Name;

                return roles.Any(r => r.Equals(roleName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
            }
    ...

        }
```

This seems to work fine and returns the roles ok with an exception. If you add roles via something like:

```
user.Roles.Add(role);

            _db.SaveChanges();
```

The code does not find the new role until you restart the app which is not good.

Through a bit of experimentation I've found that if I instantiate the unitOfWork whenever I need it the complete list of roles is found:

```
public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
            {
                  **var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();**

                var user = unitOfWork.UserRepository.GetUser(username);

                var roles = from r in user.Roles
                            select r.Name;

                if (roles != null)
                    return roles.ToArray();
                else
                    return new string[] { };
            }
```

However I don't really want to do this approach.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Is _unitOfWork.Save(); calling .SaveChanges()?

Comment: sure is. Sorry I had a mistake there have updated

Comment: What if you call ObjectContext.Refresh?

Comment: it's a dbcontext and I'm not finding a Refresh for it?

Comment: I sort of get what you mean though needing to refresh userroles

Answer (score 1):

Check if you're caching your roles in the user's cookie. Try adding `cacheRolesInCookie="false"` to the roleManager node of your `web.config`.

Comment: Apparently there is a method on the Roles collection to delete the cookie and force it to be re-built? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.deletecookie.aspx

Comment: Have checked. It's definitely not the cookie causing problems because it keeps going into my GetrolesForUser method